# Pandas apply returning DataFrame when initial df contains datetime series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm encountering some behavior I don't understand when applying a function that returns a tuple on a pandas dataframe. My intent is to have `df.apply()` return a new series, but that only seems to work when I subset the columns in my dataframe to exclude one column that's a datetime series.

This dummy example demonstrates the behavior that I'm seeing:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

def random(row):
    # Return an tuple with more elements than df has columns
    return (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

df.apply(random,axis=1)

# Output, returns new series as expected:
0    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
1    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
2    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
3    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
4    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

That works as expected, but when I add a datetime column to the dataframe...

```
df['E'] = datetime.now()

df.apply(random,axis=1)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes)
   4262         blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
-> 4263         mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
   4264         mgr._consolidate_inplace()

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in __init__(self, blocks, axes, do_integrity_check, fastpath)
   2760         if do_integrity_check:
-> 2761             self._verify_integrity()
   2762 

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in _verify_integrity(self)
   2970             if block._verify_integrity and block.shape[1:] != mgr_shape[1:]:
-> 2971                 construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
   2972         if len(self.items) != tot_items:

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   4232     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 4233         passed, implied))
   4234 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 8), indices imply (5, 5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-b57dd4b93995> in <module>()
----> 1 df.apply(random,axis=1)

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4150                     if reduce is None:
   4151                         reduce = True
-> 4152                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
   4153             else:
   4154                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4263                 index = None
   4264 
-> 4265             result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)
   4266             result.columns = res_index
   4267 

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    264                                  dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    265         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 266             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    267         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    268             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype)
    400             arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
    401 
--> 402         return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    403 
    404     def _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype=None, copy=False):

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
   5406     axes = [_ensure_index(columns), _ensure_index(index)]
   5407 
-> 5408     return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
   5409 
   5410 

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes)
   4265         return mgr
   4266     except ValueError as e:
-> 4267         construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)
   4268 
   4269 

/Users/jguillette/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   4231         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
   4232     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 4233         passed, implied))
   4234 
   4235 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 8), indices imply (5, 5)
```

The only time that I don't get an error is when the function returns a tuple with the same number of elements as the dataframe has columns, when it returns a DataFrame instead of a series.

Is there a way to change this behavior? In my case I don't need to use the datetime information in the function, but I still don't understand how excluding it changes the behavior of apply.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pandas handles the return value of apply differently based on the datatype of your df. In your first example, all datatypes are float while after adding column E, the datatypes are mixed, which caused pandas trying to reconstruct a dataframe using the returned value. I don't know the rational behind this behavior but the following should fix your problem.:

```
df.astype(object).apply(random,axis=1)
Out[64]: 
0    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
1    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
2    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
3    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
4    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: Ahhh, that's a good workaround. If I wind up using the dates I can always convert them back within the apply function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L236-L6142

```
class DataFrame(NDFrame):
def _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures=False, reduce=True):
    # skip if we are mixed datelike and trying reduce across axes
    # GH6125
    # this block will judge if it's datelike mixed type and disable reduce if true
    if (reduce and axis == 1 and self._is_mixed_type and
            self._is_datelike_mixed_type):
        reduce = False
    # try to reduce first (by default)
    # this only matters if the reduction in values is of different dtype
    # e.g. if we want to apply to a SparseFrame, then can't directly reduce
    if reduce:
        values = self.values

        # we cannot reduce using non-numpy dtypes,
        # as demonstrated in gh-12244
        if not is_extension_type(values):
            # Create a dummy Series from an empty array
            index = self._get_axis(axis)
            empty_arr = np.empty(len(index), dtype=values.dtype)
            dummy = Series(empty_arr, index=self._get_axis(axis),
                           dtype=values.dtype)

            try:
                labels = self._get_agg_axis(axis)
                result = lib.reduce(values, func, axis=axis, dummy=dummy,
                                    labels=labels)
                return Series(result, index=labels)
            except Exception:
                pass

    dtype = object if self._is_mixed_type else None
    if axis == 0:
        series_gen = (self._ixs(i, axis=1)
                      for i in range(len(self.columns)))
        res_index = self.columns
        res_columns = self.index
    elif axis == 1:
        res_index = self.index
        res_columns = self.columns
        values = self.values
        series_gen = (Series.from_array(arr, index=res_columns, name=name,
                                        dtype=dtype)
                      for i, (arr, name) in enumerate(zip(values,
                                                          res_index)))
    else:  # pragma : no cover
        raise AssertionError('Axis must be 0 or 1, got %s' % str(axis))

    i = None
    keys = []
    results = {}
    if ignore_failures:
        successes = []
        for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
            try:
                results[i] = func(v)
                keys.append(v.name)
                successes.append(i)
            except Exception:
                pass
        # so will work with MultiIndex
        if len(successes) < len(res_index):
            res_index = res_index.take(successes)
    else:
        try:
            for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
                results[i] = func(v)
                keys.append(v.name)
        except Exception as e:
            if hasattr(e, 'args'):
                # make sure i is defined
                if i is not None:
                    k = res_index[i]
                    e.args = e.args + ('occurred at index %s' %
                                       pprint_thing(k), )
            raise

    if len(results) > 0 and is_sequence(results[0]):
        if not isinstance(results[0], Series):
            index = res_columns
        else:
            index = None

        result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)
        result.columns = res_index

        if axis == 1:
            result = result.T
        result = result._convert(datetime=True, timedelta=True, copy=False)

    else:

        result = Series(results)
        result.index = res_index

    return result
```

i found the source code behind your problem, for detailed reason you may check GH6125 as the comment said.
my resolution was some stupid as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
class TMP():
    def __init__(self, a, **kws):
        self.a = a
        self.__dict__.update(kws)
def func(line):
    return TMP(line['a'], 'x', 'y')
se = df.apply(func, axis=1)
se
> 0    <__main__.TMP object at 0x11122f390>
  1    <__main__.TMP object at 0x11122f400>
  2    <__main__.TMP object at 0x11122f438>
  dtype: object
se.apply(lambda tmp: tmp.a)
> 0    1
  1    2
  2    3 
  dtype: int64
```

a second solution is ensure func to return a series(seems slower)

```
def func(line):
    return pd.Series(['a', 'x', 'y'])
df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

hope that help.

Comment: GH6125 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/6126/commits/b3b1d3ea9dc1dc6f5c49063eaf271490fce2e31b